# How to solve a non-linear equation

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I want to solve an equation $$\log \left(\frac{b}{y}\right)=\left(\frac{x}{y}-a\right)^{\beta}.~~~~~~~~~(1)$$

```
Solve[Log[b/y] == (x/y - a)^\[Beta], y]
```

Here $b$, $x$, and $a$ are constants (In principle, we have $x/y\simeq a$).  I want to find the solution $y=?$

If $a=0$, the solution is $$y^*=\left(-\frac{\beta x^{\beta}}{W\left(\beta\left(-b^{-\beta}\right) x^{\beta}\right)}\right)^{1/\beta},~~~~~~~~~(2)$$
where $W$ is the ProductLog function in MATHEMATICA.

I try to use $y=y^*+c*x^\gamma$ to find the correction term, but I failed.  I guess that the correction term is not like $c*x^\gamma$.

How can I find the correction term? For my problem, $a$ is important and can be ignored.

Thanks!

======================================================

***In principle, this problem is still not solved.  For my problem, $x$ has some relation with $a$, which is unknown until now. Thus, $a$ can not tend to $0$. Besides, I assume that $a\to 0$, the result is not very good.***

Comment: The introduction about $W$ function.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: Do you have a good reason to suspect that a closed form solution even exists?

Comment: I am not sure about this. But I believe that the solution may exist. For example, if $\beta=2$, I have found the solution.  Now I just want to find a solution which is better than Eq.~2.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit  At least, the numerical solution exists.

Comment: Be careful: you shouldn't use `N` as a variable name - it's a built-in.

Comment: @flinty Thanks, I corrected it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve). First, the zeroth order solution:

```
y0 = y /. First @ Solve[Log[b/y]==(x/y-a)^/.a->0, y]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

> (-((x^ )/ProductLog[-b^- x^ ]))^(1/)

Then using [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve):

```
AsymptoticSolve[Log[b/y] == (x/y-a)^, {y, y0}, a->0]
```

> {{y -> ConditionalExpression[(-((x^*)/ProductLog[-((x^*)/b^)]))^^(-1) +
> ((-Log[b/(-((x^*)/ProductLog[-((x^*)/b^)]))^^(-1)] +
> (x/(-((x^*)/ProductLog[-((x^*)/b^)]))^^(-1))^)*
> (-((x^*)/ProductLog[-((x^*)/b^)]))^^(-1))/
> (-1 + *(x/(-((x^*)/ProductLog[-((x^*)/b^)]))^^(-1))^) -
> (a(-1 - Log[b/(-((x^*)/ProductLog[-((x^*)/b^)]))^^(-1)] +
> *Log[b/(-((x^*)/ProductLog[-((x^*)/b^)]))^^(-1)] +
> (x/(-((x^*)/ProductLog[-((x^*)/b^)]))^^(-1))^)*
> (x/(-((x^*)/ProductLog[-((x^*)/b^)]))^^(-1))^*
> (-((x^*)/ProductLog[-((x^*)/b^)]))^(2/))/
> (x*(-1 + *(x/(-((x^*)/ProductLog[-((x^*)/b^)]))^^(-1))^)^2),
> -Log[b/(-((x^*)/ProductLog[-((x^*)/b^)]))^^(-1)] +
> (x/(-((x^*)/ProductLog[-((x^*)/b^)]))^^(-1))^ == 0]}}

Comment: My MMA  does not give the answer for your ''AsymptoticSolve[Log[b/y] == (x/y-a)^, {y, y0}, a->0]''                Can you give me the version of your MMA?  Thanks!

Comment: @Blueka You can use `Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "AsymptoticSolve"]["VersionIntroduced"]` to find out when a function enters the language. In this case you would find that AsymptoticSolve was introduced in M12.

Comment: Are there other methods to find the solution?   This solution works not very good.

Comment: @Blueka Could you clarify the "not very good" aspects to the solution?

Comment: The convergence is very slow.  For example, when I choose the parameters, I plotted Eq.~1, I can find a solution $y_1\simeq 14.18$, while I use your formula, the numerical solution is  $y_2=11.91$.  The difference is a bit big for me. Here my $a=0.01$

Comment: For my problem, $a$ is related to $x$, i.e., if $a$ is small, $x$ should be small. Maybe I should find the exact solution but it is too hard. While if I added the correction term a^2, the solution is too long, it is not easy to analyze.